# Restore app data from a copied 'com.company.appname' folder

Tags: adb, backup, restore

Before wiping my Nexus 7 (2012), I created an app backup using the Backup function of the [Nexus Root Toolkit](http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/) (v1.8.2). This produced a large .ab file.

I want to restore a single app to the newly back-to-stock tablet.

I extracted the .ab file to a TAR using [Droid Explorer](https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer), and from that, extracted the particular 'com.company.appname' folder. I tried simply copying that into the `sdcard/Android/data/` folder, but the app doesn't see the data.

Any ideas?

P.S. I'm on Android 4.4 KitKat and trying to restore [SeriesGuide](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.battlelancer.seriesguide) (com.battlelancer.seriesguide)

Answer (score 1):

Very likely, you need to `adb push` them to the appropriate folder in your `data/` partition, which is different than your `/sdcard/` partition.

Comment: Right, if the app isn't seeing the data then it's probably using the main `/data` partition instead of the SD card's data folder.